# Android layout external CSS

Tags: android, css, xml, layout, styles

I have multiple buttons in my xml layout (for Andoid) with quite duplicity:

```
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/tr" //duplicity everywhere but here
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1" //and here
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/rb"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/button" />

        ...
```

Is there anything like CSS or some classes/templates for me to not spend my whole evening by changing `50dp` to `55dp` 100 times?

I'm using android studio 2.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  You can use Themes and Styles. Android has a nice tutorial of it found here: [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). To control how all `ImageButtons` look and function, you can use the `android:imageButtonStyle`.  Eg:

***themes.xml***

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

***styles.xml***

```
<style name="ImageButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
</style>
```

This will allow you to adjust all the sizes in one go.  Of course, if you wish to only have a few of the `ImageButtons` to use the given style then remove the `android:imageButtonStyle` line and instead, do the following with each `ImageButton`.

```
<ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/tr" //duplicity everywhere but here
        android:id="@+id/button1" //and here
        style="@style/ImageButtonStyle"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could (have) use(d) a custom style (or) a referenced attribute value.

If u had done so, you can easily change the attribute/style in one file a see it reflect over all widgets using that.

You can refer to **[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)**